# Using Cloudera Manager to decommission a node

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera

I am new to using Cloudera Manager. I have a 2 node Hadoop cluster on AWS that uses Cloudera Standard edition. I noticed that the Cloudera Manager was not able to establish a connection with one of the nodes, say Node 1. For some reason, i decided to decommission Node 1 and add a new node. So, i created a new ec2 instance and attached the volume of the instance i wanted to decommission. I have shutdown the Node 1 ec2 instance.

Now, i have tried to decommission that node from the Cluster using Cloudera Manager. However, it tries to stop the roles on the Node 1 (which is now shut down) and it fails there. The roles that were running on that machine were RegionServer, Impala, TaskTracker, Datanode and Gateway.

It fails when it tries to shutdown the TaskTracker role.

I am not sure what to do now. Please help.

Comment: Please update your description with the error message and relevant logs for the TaskTracker shutdown failure. That'll help a lot when debugging this problem. Cloudera Manager should keep a history of the command where you can find this information.

Comment: I get an error message saying "Command 'DecommissionWithWait' failed for service 'mapreduce1". I don't see the TaskTracker logs because that node is not even up and running. Another point to note is when I login to the JobTracker WebUI, I see that the node that i brought down is already in the 'Excluded Nodes' list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this situation, because CM can't connect to Node 1, can we simply delete Node 1 from the cluster rather than decommissioning it? This will remove Node 1's roles from the rest of the services.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cloudera documentation decommission action stops certain roles and puts the node(host) in a special "decommissioned" state - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/archives/cloudera-manager-4/v4-5-3/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-User-Guide/cmeeug_topic_7_8.html. Having this in mind, and the fact you don't have access to this node, the most probable reason for your failure is because the Cloudera Manager cannot stops the services on it.